# sql - what is the difference between these two queries?

Tags: sql, performance

```
select a.Name from rat. Assessment a where a.AssessmentId = '3'
select a.Name from rat. Assessment a where a.AssessmentId = 3
```

whats the difference performance wise ?
is it slow for the first one ?

How can i know if sql server has casted the the column or value to match the the column type or value type ?

I saw the execution plan. cant understand much.

Comment: Try it. Compare the query plans. One assumes that the first does more work (convert a string to a number).

Comment: What do your own tests suggest?

Comment: It depends on the SQL implementation. But I would guess any SQL compiler will create the same expression tree for this.

Comment: I guess i need to learn to see the query plans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one requires type casting (assuming that AssessmentID is a numeric data type), which has its performance overhead. In this case it will be negligible, but in more complex queries there can be performance difference. In some cases, MySQL can't use index efficiently if it needs to do type casting.

Answer (score 2):

That's not easy to say without knowing which database you use, what the involved types are.

Many databases try to convert/cast constant types to the column type once so they don't have to do it when they read each row from disk. But there is no guarantee that this happens, when it happens.

But not every database tries to match types. So for some of them, you will get an error or you won't get any results (because a number isn't a string, so the query doesn't really match anything).

Comment: This is sql server 2008 express. Will it try to typecast ?

Comment: @bilalfazlani: I'm not using Microsoft products.

Answer (score 1):

although this both works but if the data type of `AssessmentID` is numeric, the second query is faster because there is no casting required while the first one requires the server to cast the value first into numeric.